# Base class pointer to derived type

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

So I've been trying to wrap my head around casts. In other languages, I've seen code like

```cpp
Player player = (DifferentObject as Player)
```

Especially when it comes to multiplayer for example. My question is, how can I replicate this kind of code in C++? If I use

```
A* a = new B();
```

I need to cast a whenever I want to call B functions.

```
struct A
{
    A() { }
    virtual ~A() { }

    void a_only_func() const
    {
        std::cout << "a only func." << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void a_virtual_func() const
    {
        std::cout << "a virtual func." << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    B() { }
    ~B() { }

    void b_only_func() const
    {
        std::cout << "Hello." << std::endl;
    }

    void a_virtual_func() const
    {
        std::cout << "derived." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B()
    ((B*)a)->b_only_func();              /* identical - prints Hello.
    (static_cast<B*>(a))->b_only_func();  * identical */
    a->a_only_func();                    // prints a only func.
    a->a_virtual_func();                 // prints derived.
    ((B*)a)->a_virtual_func();           // prints derived
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see, everything works as expected. But not without the explicit casts. Am I missing something subtle here?

**Update**

The following seems to represent the idiom I was looking for.

```
void do_stuff(Player* player)
{
    DerivedPlayer localVar = dynamic_cast<DerivedPlayer*>(player);
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be passing something which is only guaranteed to be an `A` (that is, an `A *`) to a function expecting a `B`. If `B` has extra data, and the function tries to access it, subtle bugs can result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use casts like that when calling member functions. When you instantiate `B` you can assign it to a variable of type `B*` and still call functions declared in both 'A' and 'B'

```
B *b = new B();

b->b_only_func();     // identical - prints Hello.
b->b_only_func();     // identical
b->a_only_func();     // prints a only func.
b->a_virtual_func();  // prints derived.
b->a_virtual_func();  // prints derived
```

If you need to keep a pointer to the base class `A` you can use `dynamic_cast` to retrieve a pointer to a derived class.

```
A* a = new B();

B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
```

If variable `a` is not derived from type `B` the `dynamic_cast` will return `NULL`

```
if(b == NULL)
{
   // a is not derived from type 'B'
}
```

This requires that 'A' be a polymorphic type and have at least one virtual member function.

Comment: But the whole idea is to have the class be 'Player', that can be cast to whatever derived class it needs to be.

Comment: Updated to reflect more of what you're looking for.

Comment: This does **not** require `A` to have a virtual destructor. A virtual destructor is required **if** the code deletes an object of a derived type through a pointer to a base type. That's certainly common, but it doesn't give rise to an absolute requirement.

Comment: Oops. That should read "at least one virtual function". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a behavior wherein each class needs to provide own implementation for a method then you need to put those functions in the base class and mark them as `virtual`, Each derived class shall overidde these methods.This allows you to call appropriate methods depending upon the concrete object type rather than the pointer.

If you need to call methods which are specific to derived class through a base class pointer then, yes you do need explicit cast. It is better to use a `dynamic_cast` if the classes are polymorphic. But note that if you need to do this too often then you probably missed something in your design and you must revisit the design.

Answer (score 2):

> not without explicit casts?

If you are calling the virtual function with base class pointers, you don't need to use explicit cast. It is decided at run time based on which type of objects the base class pointer is pointed to.

If you are calling non-virtual function, then if you assign derived class objects to base class pointers, if you need to call non-virtual function of derived class, you need cast.

The above should explain the following results:

```
A* a = new B(); //don't miss ; 
//you use base class pointer to point to derived class object
((B*)a)->b_only_func();              
//identical - prints Hello. b_only_func is not virtual, 
//you need cast in order to really call B's function, 
//otherwise, you will get compile error since 
//b_only_func() is not a member of a
a->a_only_func();    // prints a only func.
a->a_virtual_func();   // prints derived. this is expected because of polymorphism
((B*)a)->a_virtual_func();           // prints derived, not needed in this case
delete a;
```